# navigator is not working inphonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hello guys I got an issue with navigator in my previous app it was working but now it is not working  i tried in many way but couldn't figure out the issue.

```
phonegap -v is 3.3.0-0.19.6
cordova -v  is 3.3.1-0.4.2
```

for installing plugins i tried below types

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

Below is my config.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.company.multipleScreen" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>Hello Cordova</name>
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
<preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
<preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
<preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0" />
<preference name="PageLength" value="0" />
<preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page" />
<preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated" />
<feature name="LocalStorage">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
</feature>
<name>testing</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
</feature>
<feature name="Media">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSound" />
</feature>
<feature name="File">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<feature name="Capture">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCapture" />
</feature>
<feature name="Globalization">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVGlobalization" />
</feature>
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
</feature>
```

The code i tried to implement for showing alert is

```
navigator.notification.alert("Unable to connect to server !");
```

and my other requirement is camera it is also not working

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
image.src = imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current Cordova version 3.4.0 you have to manually install all plugins via `cordova plugin add`

So in your case, referring to https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/dev/doc/index.md, you need to do:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

I would recommend reading the documentation about plugins:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/cordova_plugins_pluginapis.md.html#Plugin%20APIs

Comment: thanks for help i tried but navigator is not working

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed by adding

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device   
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
```